# my code is about to increment the counter in the browser when we click in the increment button

Tags: javascript, html

when we click on the increment button the counter shows in the browser not incrementing.

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el");
console.log(countEl);
let count = 0;

function increment() {
  count = count + 1;
  countEl.innertext = count;
}
```

```html
<h1>people entered</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
<button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive. in your code you wrote

```
.innertext = ...
```

which should have been

```
.innerText = ...
```

Also, it is better to attach event click on the button rather on rely on `onclick` since you can't guarantee if the script file has already been loaded or not.

```js
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el");
console.log(countEl);
let count = 0;
let button = document.getElementById("increment-btn");

button.addEventListener('click', increment);

function increment() {
  
  count = count + 1;
  countEl.innerText = count;
}
```

```html
<h1>people entered</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
<button id="increment-btn" >INCREMENT</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function increment() {
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el");
let count = countEl.innerHTML;
console.log(count);
  count++;
   countEl.innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<h1>people entered</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
<button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
```